# Image always loads blurry on wordpress webpage and doesn't load on Safari

Tags: html, wordpress, image, cross-browser, resolution

I have been working on the website (CMS: Wordpress) for my father's cafe' - [www.barcaffecitta.it](http://www.barcaffecitta.it) and I am having a problem getting the image to come out clear and not blurry and work on all browsers. The image began as a TIFF with a 7320 × 5484 resolution (64 MB) and I resized it initially to a TIFF with 2000 x 1498 resolution and set the html width: 100% and height: 90% which made it work great in safari but I found out that TIFF isn't supported on other browsers automatically. I thus tried converting it to a PNG and to a JPEG but every time the image turns out blurry or doesn't load in safari at all. If you take a look at the website now there is a JPEG with a 960 x 619 resolution with the html height and width set in px exactly at the resolution. If you could suggest a route to take starting from the original TIFF or what is customary to do with images please let me know. 
Also, what should the HTML height and width be in pixels when the picture is uploaded and whatever I choose will this resize automatically if a different monitor is used?!

Thank you!

Comment: your jpg is 300x193, and you display it like it is 960x619. Of course it looks blurry

Comment: If I look at my media in wordpress, the picture is actually what I said it was. (Dimensions: 960 × 619) The 300x193 is what wordpress automatically inserts it into the page as but that can be changed by editing the html width and height in the <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://www.barcaffecitta.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Caffè-Città-JPEG-cropped960x619-300x193.jpg" width="900px" height="619px" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-90" />
```

1. è letter in image url
2. à letter in image url
3. width="900px"
4. height="619px"

these are reasons why image is blured and even not loaded on some browsers. It should be like: (but **re-upload** image with name "Caffe-Citta.jpg")

```
<img style="width:960px;" alt="Caffè-Città" src="http://www.barcaffecitta.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Caffe-Citta.jpg" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-90" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I copy and pasted the code you provided and safari still won't load the image and has a small question mark in a blue box and mozilla now won't load at all. If you have any other suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them. When I insert the images I do it through the add media button on wordpress not manually so the syntax is automated and should be correct. All I did was adjust the height and width values. Also another general rule of thumb, what would you have done with my starting TIFF if I wanted to insert the image in my website?

Comment: resize TIFF, convert to jpeg with 90% quality and save with CORRECT name. My code will not work unless you re-upload jpg image with correct name. (without è à letters )